# Sublime text can't understand gets.chomp

Tags: ruby, sublimetext, gets, chomp

I wrote this simple program in ruby using Sublime Text and for some reason if I build it using Sublime text inbuilt system then I get the following error

```
`deposit': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Its running perfectly if I run it using cmd.

```
class BankAccount
    def initialize(name)
        @transactions = []
        @balance = 0
    end
    def deposit
        print "How much do you want to deposit?"
        amount = gets.chomp
        @balance += amount.to_f
        puts "$#{amount} is deposited"
    end
    def show_balance
        puts "Your balance is #{@balance}"
    end
end
bank_account = BankAccount.new("Rohit Begani")
bank_account.class # => BankAccount
bank_account.deposit
bank_account.show_balance
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sublime can't handle interactive input on its own. You can either run your script through [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) or create a customized [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) to open a command prompt and then run the code. Fortunately, this isn't too difficult. Create a new file in Sublime with the following contents:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "c:/ruby193/bin/ruby.exe", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.ruby",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_dir"
}
```

Save it as `Packages/User/Ruby_cmd.sublime-build`, where `Packages` is the directory opened when selecting `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`. Select `Tools -> Build System -> Ruby_cmd`, and run your file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

This should work on all versions of Windows from XP on up. It is not intended for OSX or Linux, though, as they don't have the `start` and `cmd` programs...